# Disable Hover effect in Essential Grid - Just on Mobile Phones

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugins, mousehover

I have a website [tyloz.com](http://www.tyloz.com/). There are 4 panels on the homepage which are serving as landing page of my website. Hover effect is added to these panel which is activated on phone as well.
From Phone a user has to tap twice on a panel to go to that specific link. I just want to have hover and overlay on desktop. Is there a way to disable hover and double tap on phone?
Please visit the website for better understanding.

I added below code;

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .minimal-light .esg-navigationbutton:hover,
.minimal-light .esg-filterbutton:hover,
.minimal-light .esg-sortbutton:hover,
.minimal-light .esg-sortbutton-order:hover,
.minimal-light .esg-cartbutton a:hover,
.minimal-light .esg-filterbutton.selected {
                                            background-color:#fff;
                                            border-color:#bbb;
                                            color:#333;
                                            box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
                                          }

.minimal-light .esg-navigationbutton:hover * { color:#333; }

.minimal-light .esg-sortbutton-order.tp-desc:hover {
                                                    border-color:#bbb;
                                                    color:#333;
                                                    box-shadow: 0px -3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.13) !important;
                                                   }

.minimal-light .esg-filter-checked { 
                                    padding:1px 3px;
                                    color:#cbcbcb;
                                    background:#cbcbcb;
                                    margin-left:7px;
                                    font-size:9px;
                                    font-weight:300;
                                    line-height:9px;
                                    vertical-align: middle;
                                    }
.minimal-light .esg-filterbutton.selected .esg-filter-checked,
.minimal-light .esg-filterbutton:hover .esg-filter-checked {
                                                            padding:1px 3px 1px 3px;
                                                            color:#fff;
                                                            background:#000;
                                                            margin-left:7px;
                                                            font-size:9px;
                                                            font-weight:300;
                                                            line-height:9px;
                                                            vertical-align: middle;


                                                   }
```

}

Comment: @Jake Thank you for the reply. No, I am still struggling with the code especially Essential Grid. I will get back once its sorted. :)

Comment: What are the effects (CSS styles) that are being applied when you hover over the panels?

Comment: @Jake Thank you for support! I edited my post to show you the code that I am using now. There is no difference in the behavior. I have to double tap on the phone similar to double clicking on desktop. Apologies for the delayed response.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would make a difference but you may want to try using a separate `@media` element for each **set** of styles. You will also have to remove the `:hover` effects outside of the `@media` elements for it to only work on larger devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media` in CSS to define how your code will behave when certain parameters are met.

Please note, using `min-width: 1024px` will only apply this to small laptops and up, excluding tablets and mobile. You can also use this with `max-width` at a value less than 1024 to define how your site will work on a mobile/tablet.

Just apply your hover effects, etc. to larger devices and not smaller ones.

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .css-class:hover {
    attribute: value;
    attribute: value;
  }
}
```

Check out [this resource](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to see what else you can do with `@media`.